# Single return point or multiple inline returns?

Tags: coding-style

I often see a piece of code similar to the following (language doesn't matter):

```
private Result method() {
    var result = initialValue;

    if (condition) {
        result = otherResult;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here is a little bit refactored version:

```
private Result method() {

    if (condition) {
        return otherResult;
    }

    return initialValue;
}
```

Pros of the first solution as authors say is the single return point in the method. From my point of view the second variant is much better without additional variable despite the two return points. Also in case condition is `true` the value of `result` becomes to be set twice.
Do any additional pros and cons exist here? What case is better nevertheless?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever way you write your code, compiler tries to generate the best possible/optimized code. You can try to see the generated assembly code for both and see whether it really makes difference or not. But from code simplicity point of view, first one looks better.

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you're doing really.. In this simplified example it may not be apparent, but the first way is better if you need to do something after checking the condition regardless of what the result is.

This is not possible in the second version since the function instantly returns. Any code written after the if block will not be executed if the condition passes.